# Revision clouds in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, toolbar

I was looking for an easy way to make revision cloud in Excel (20XX). I currently do it using a very weird copy/paste method, but it takes way too long!

I recently stumbled across an Excel toolbar on a different machine which lets you draw revision clouds around a cell, but the toolbar does not work as the files are missing on that machine (that is the error message)

So, I have two questions

1. Does anyone know/use this toolbar?
2. If not, has anyone tried or know how to draw revision clouds using vb (I don't want to use the autoshape callout shape).

Comment: the toolbar is called optional-toolbar, so i guess it was custom built. Not much help there.

Comment: solved it. Should I close this question? How can I do that?